# How can I compute $\pi ^{20}$, where $\pi$ is a permutation?

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

Suppose you had the permutation $\pi= \left( \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9\\ 7 & 2 & 9 & 8 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 6 & 5 \end{array} \right)$.

How would you compute $\pi ^{20}$? I know that if you express a permutation as a product of disjoint cycles, such as $\pi = (1 \enspace 7)(3 \enspace 9 \enspace 5)(4 \enspace 8 \enspace 6)$, then $\pi ^{20} = (1 \enspace 7)^{20}(3 \enspace 9 \enspace 5)^{20}(4 \enspace 8 \enspace 6)^{20}$, but I do not know where top go from here. How do you multiply/square/cube/etc cycles?

Also, I've worked out that the order of $\pi$ is 6, since this is the lowest common multiple of the lengths of each of its disjoint cycles. Is this correct?

What about if you had a permutation which gave one long cycle if expressed as a product of disjoint cycles?

Comment: What's $(1\ 7)^1$? $(1\ 7)^2$? $(1\ 7)^3$? $(1\ 7)^4$?

Comment: If $c$ is a cycle of length $n$, then $c^n$ is the identity, and $c^p=c^q$ whenever $p\equiv q\pmod{n}$. (basically, that's why the cyclic group $C_n$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$).

Comment: @Akiva Weinberger: That is the exact question I am trying to find the answer to. I do not know how powers act on a cycle.

Comment: Do you know how to multiply permutations?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: So you're saying that $\pi ^{20} = \pi ^{2}$, since $20 \equiv 2 \quad (mod \quad 6)$?

Comment: $\pi$ is not a cycle. To find $n$ such that $\pi^n=\mathrm{id}$, take the LCM of the lengths of its cycles. This is $6$, so $\pi^6=\mathrm{id}$, thus $\pi^{20}=\pi^2$, yes.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: Of course, let me try that again. Since $\pi ^{20} = (1 \enspace 7)^{20}(3 \enspace 9 \enspace 5)^{20}(4 \enspace 8 \enspace 6)^{20}$, we get that  $\pi ^{20} = (1 \enspace 7)^{0}(3 \enspace 9 \enspace 5)^{2}(4 \enspace 8 \enspace 6)^{2}$, because $20 \equiv 0 \quad (mod \quad 2)$ and $20 \equiv 2 \quad (mod \quad 3)$?

Answer (score 1):

Since $\pi^{20} = \pi^2$:
$$\pi^2 = (17)^2(395)^2(486)^2 = (359)(468)$$

Comment: $(17)^2$ is not $(17)$.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but why is $(3 \ 9 \ 5)^{2}=(3 \ 5 \ 9)$? What is the rule for what $(3 \ 9 \ 5)^{k}$ equals?

Comment: @user2910074 Reverse the cycle (that is, read it backwards), and make a circular permutation to push $3$ at the begining: $(395)^{-1}=(593)=(359)$. Notice that a cycle $(a_1a_2\dots a_n)$ means $a_1\to a_2,a_2\to a_3\dots a_{n-1}\to a_n,a_n\to a_1$. The inverse is thus $a_n\to a_{n-1}\dots a_2\to a_1,a_1\to a_n$.

Comment: @ErickWong True, thanks for telling.

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut Thanks again for the response. I understand how to find the inverse $\pi ^{-1}$ of a permutation and see that $\pi ^{2}=\pi ^{-1}$, since $2 \equiv -1 \ (mod \ 3)$. However, what if it was not possible to use this method? For example, how would you compute $(3 \ 6 \ 1 \ 7)^{2}$?

Comment: @user2910074 Do you know how to multiply permutations?  What's $(3 6 1 7)(3 6 1 7)$?  (Yes, there is a faster way to deduce what $(3 6 1 7)^2$ looks like, but this is a good opportunity to build up your intuition on this rather than learning rules with no context.)

Comment: @user2910074 For a cycle $c$, compute $c^n$ by taking one element every $n$, and when you are at the end, continue as if the permutation were written as many times as needed (or equivalently, restart at the beginning, taking into account the last jump).

Comment: @Erick Wong I know that if you have 2 permutations, say $\pi$ and $\sigma$, then $\pi \sigma = \pi \circ \sigma = \pi ( \sigma (a) )$ for each $a \in \sigma$. Not sure how this definition would allow me to find $(3 \ 6 \ 1 \ 7)^{2}$ though?

Comment: $(3617)(3617) = (13)(67)$ because you first fix 1 (for example), then you see where it goes: 1 goes to 7, and 7 goes to 3. Then you see 3 goes to 6 and 6 to 1, so you are done with the first cycle. Now you take 6 and you see it goes to 1 and then 1 goes to 7 and you get your second cycle. Hope you understand :)

Comment: @M4g1ch Thanks, understand it now.